# Can I deploy an executable JAR file to Azure PaaS?

Tags: java, azure, eclipse-plugin, executable-jar, azure-worker-roles

I am using Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse, and I am trying to deploy my Java (actually Scala) application to Windows Azure.

In order to deploy it to Azure PaaS services, as I understood, I must wrap it in a WAR file, and deploy it together with a JDK and an application server of my choice (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.). The plugin for Eclipse pack them all into a Windows Azure package and then deploy it.

My question is:

**How do I deploy a Java application to Azure, which doesn't need a web interface, and therefore I pack it as a JAR and not WAR? Do Azure Java applications must be packed in a WAR?**

Using the Eclipse plugin, it does give me the option to choose a JAR file to deploy, but I didn't manage to make it work. Did anyone experience that?

Thanks,

Comment: did you overcome this issue at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if these specific pages existed when you wrote your original question, but Azure has instructional page for uploading and configuring a java application.

I can't provide specific instructions to you because there are too many different options and configuration settings for first deploying your jar.

Once it is deployed, there are still another set of configurations/properties that Azure expects.

Here is the instructional article for deployment options:
[Deploy your app to Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/)

Here is the instructional article for Java/JVM specific configuration settings to deploy a WAR or JAR:
[Upload custom Java web app to Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/)

Look at the springboot section specifically, it has an as example that shows how to run an executable jar:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\my-web-project.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finally, here is another instructional article for creating Java/JVM apps in Azure:
[Create a Java web app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/)